# MediaPlayer with surround effect?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Is it possible to force the android `MediaPlayer` to emulate the 5.1 surround while playing a track like the default player (at least on Samsung devices) does? Any useful links and suggestions appreciated, spent a lot of time searching for a solution but still found nothing.

Comment: just for curiosity, what device are you developing for?

Comment: @user1527232 actually I'm targeting all devices beginning with 2.2 (which often means additional complexity and issues..)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain myself very well. How can you emulate a 5.1 surround on a stereo device? Is it a matter of merging tracks to fit two channels or what...? I'm as dumb as curious and didn't get the point ^^

Comment: actually I'm not familiar with audio, that's why I asked this question. There's a "5.1 surround" button in the Samsung stock player. Sometimes the sound becomes horrible when it is toggled so I really doubt there's a real surround, just like you said. More likely this is emulated. But I got no clue how

Comment: ouh ok, I really don't know what it does. The only thing I can think of is that if you play an actual 5.1 surround track into a stereo device you have to adapt it somehow, if you just play the 2 front channels of 5.1 in the stereo channels you'll lose a lot of sound...but emulating 5.1 while playing a stereo track in a stereo device really doesn't make any sense to me...XD

Comment: actually same here.. but take a look at this screenshot (top left) http://cs407218.vk.me/v407218837/7182/HEFfOlBmuSk.jpg

Comment: wow, I just googled for "headphones 5.1" and came to know that you can actually play 5.1 on these kind of headphones...they've got more than 2 speakers... +1. Over.